# WPF ScrollViewer in other controls

Tags: wpf, treeview, scrollviewer

When I have a control like a WPF Treeview,
Naturally when the contents of that treeview exceed the maximum height or width a scroll appears.

Is there a way to obtain that scroll to move it or disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to roll your own [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx). This will allow you to define exactly the controls that are used to build the TreeView. The part of the template that will display your TreeView items is the ItemsPresenter, so this is obviously a required part of the template.